# Call a php function on text selection in text area

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, forms

I have a text area in form. When some text from text area is being selected, I have to enable a button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do something when text is selected, take a look at the [.select()](http://api.jquery.com/select/) jQuery event.  Then you can enable/disable the button however you like.

Example from the jQuery page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { color:blue; }
  div { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>

    Click and drag the mouse to select text in the inputs.
  </p>
  <input type="text" value="Some text" />
  <input type="text" value="to test on" />

  <div></div>
<script>
    $(":input").select( function () { 
      $("div").text("Something was selected").show().fadeOut(1000); 
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onfocus` event of textarea for this kind of job.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done with Javascript, because when some text is being selected, that is only on the client side. And with jQuery show(); hide(); (CSS) it should be fairly easy.

Comment: what i was not sure is which event to use to trigger when text is selected in text area